# Trying to find 2nd power series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

For the equation $ xy'' + 2xy' + 6e^xy = 0 $, I need to find the first 3 nonzero terms in each of two linearly independent solutions about x=0. I changed this to the form of $$x^2y''+x[xp(x)]y'+[x^2q(x)]y=0$$ yielding $$x^2y''+2x^2y'+6xe^xy=0$$
I found the first answer to be $$ y = x-4x^2+17/3x^3-47/12x^4 $$ which matches the books answer. I found this using that that $ F(r) = r(r-1) + pr + q $, where $xp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{inf}p_nx^n$ and $x^2q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{inf}q_nx^n$  This gave me that $ r_1 =1,  r_2=0 $.  I plugged into the indicial equation $$ F(r+n)a_n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k((r+k)p_{n-k} + q_{n-k}) = 0 $$(given in the book) and then applied this to $$y_{1}(x)=x^{r_1}(1+\sum_{n=1}^{inf} a_{n}(r_1)x^n)$$ using the $a_n$'s that I got from the indicial equation.

This is where I am stuck. My book (Boyce and DiPrima) says that $$y_2=ay_1(x)ln(x)+x^{r_2}[1+\sum_{n=1}^{inf}c_n(r_2)x^n]$$

It says that you can plug the form of the series solutions for y into the original equation but I'm not sure what they mean by that.  I tried to take this form and differentiate twice then plug back in;  it quickly got very complicated and I doubted that was the correct way to proceed.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

---

Thanks for the guidance. Here is where I am now:

So I started with my eqn for $y_2$ and found y' and y'':$$y'=a(y_1'lnx+y_1/x)+\sum_{n=1}^{inf}nC_nx^{n-1}$$ $$y''=a(y_1''lnx+2y_1'/x-y_1/x^2)+\sum_{n=1}^{inf}(n-1)(n)x^{n-2}$$

I then set about plugging these into the original equation:
$$xy''=a(y_1''xlnx+2y_1'-y_1/x)+\sum_{n=1}^{inf}(n-1)(n)x^{n-1}$$
$$2xy'=2a(y_1'xlnx+y_1)+2\sum_{n=1}^{inf}nC_nx^n$$
$$6e^xy=6e^x(ay_1lnx+1)+\sum_{n=1}^{inf}c_n/(n-1)! x^{2n-1}$$
How do I deal with the 2n in the last term?
Am I correct in assuming that after I figure that out, I consolidate into one statement within the summation and one outside, set both equal to 0, and find a recurrence relation?  Also, am I missing an easier way to be doing this?

Comment: That is the correct route, actually. However, it helps a great deal to avoid using $y_1$ explicitly in the second solution. Instead, use the fact that it's a solution---i.e. that it satisfies the ODE---and use that while you're simplifying it. It helps to use Mathematica if you can.

Comment: You have already found the solution, in general (ie for $y_1$. This is a solution to the ODE. The general form of $y_2$ is given as above. You know $y_1$ from before, and you know what $r_2$ is from solving the indicial equation. Depending on your methods, have you solved for a general form of $c_n$? You know that $y_2$ is a solution to the ODE. Use what you have and see what plugging into does. Series solutions are generally messy, especially the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

References and personal experience suggest that the original author of this question, despite this temporary stall, has the extraordinary brainpower to overcome the difficulties of this problem!

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer to the question.